# SQL equivalent to pandas transformation (groupy + transform)

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, databricks-sql

Suppose you have the following table:

| TagName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1P1132A | 0.0 |
| 1P1132B | 0.0 |
| 1P1133A | 0.0 |
| 1P1133B | 3.0 |
| 1P1133C | 2.0 |
| 1P1133D | 1.0 |

And by performing some transformations in pandas I get a column of tags grouped by tag number and all the letters it has (code and final table below)

```py
# Add a column for tag number (without letter)
pattern = re.compile(r"\d{1}P\d+")        
df["TagNo"] = df["TagName"].apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group(0))

#Get letter tag
df["TagLetter"] = df["TagName"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(pattern, "", x))

#Group by TagNo. and TagLetter
df["PairRef"] = (
    df
    [["TagNo", "TagLetter"]]\
        .groupby("TagNo")["TagLetter"]
        .transform(lambda x: "/".join(sorted(set(x))))
)

df["PairRef"] = df["TagNo"] + " " + df["PairRef"]
```

Transformed table:

| TagName | Value | TagNo | TagLetter | PairRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1P1132A | 0.0 | 1P1132 | A | 1P1132 A/B |
| 1P1132B | 0.0 | 1P1132 | B | 1P1132 A/B |
| 1P1133A | 0.0 | 1P1133 | A | 1P1133 A/B/C/D |
| 1P1133B | 3.0 | 1P1133 | B | 1P1133 A/B/C/D |
| 1P1133C | 2.0 | 1P1133 | C | 1P1133 A/B/C/D |
| 1P1133D | 1.0 | 1P1133 | D | 1P1133 A/B/C/D |

How would you do it in SQL?

So far I know how to create columns TagNo and TagLetter(using very very simple queries), but I have no idea how to make a column PairRef.

```
SELECT TagName, AvgValue, SUBSTRING(TagName,1,len(TagName)-1) as TagNo, SUBSTRING(TagName, -1) as TagLetter from table
```

Comment: In general, groupby-transform is equivalent to a window function in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html) as an example:

```
duckdb.sql("""
from df
select 
   tagname,
   value,
   tagname[:-1] as TagNo,
   tagname[-1]  as TagLetter,
   tagno || ' ' || group_concat(tagletter, '/') 
      over (partition by tagno) as PairRef,
""")
```

```
┌─────────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────┬────────────────┐
│ TagName │ Value  │  TagNo  │ TagLetter │    PairRef     │
│ varchar │ double │ varchar │  varchar  │    varchar     │
├─────────┼────────┼─────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ 1P1133A │    0.0 │ 1P1133  │ A         │ 1P1133 A/B/C/D │
│ 1P1133B │    3.0 │ 1P1133  │ B         │ 1P1133 A/B/C/D │
│ 1P1133C │    2.0 │ 1P1133  │ C         │ 1P1133 A/B/C/D │
│ 1P1133D │    1.0 │ 1P1133  │ D         │ 1P1133 A/B/C/D │
│ 1P1132A │    0.0 │ 1P1132  │ A         │ 1P1132 A/B     │
│ 1P1132B │    0.0 │ 1P1132  │ B         │ 1P1132 A/B     │
└─────────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```